# How do I choose a view for a contentpresenter when there is no view model

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I suspect this question has been answered elsewhere, but I can't find it for the life of me, so please bear with me. I am also fairly new to MVVM & XAML so please let me know if I am barking up completely the wrong tree.

I am developing an educational application with different levels. On the opening screen of each level there is a button (bound to a command in a VM) which displays a modal pop-up window that contains information about the level.

The window always looks the same - there is a heading, an icon, and then some descriptive "stuff". It is the "stuff" that is causing me difficulty - sometimes is is text, sometimes text and images which are differently formatted, etc.

At the moment I have a Window control with the heading and icon bound to properties on a view model, but as I am currently seeing it the visual nature of the "stuff" makes it another view, so I have put a contentpresenter into the window, and this is where I come unstuck.

The "stuff" has no view model associated with it, because it is made up of a random collection of different visual things - images, text, etc., so I can't set the content to a viewmodel and let an implicit datatemplate do it.

How do I choose the view I want to display in the Window for "stuff" when there is no corresponding view model? Or, am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Slightly long winded question, but I hope it makes sense.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Where does this 'stuff' come from and how do you decide what to show?

Comment: Originally, the "stuff" comes from the paper-based version of the education programme that the game is for. Each level of the programme has an opening chapter which describes what will be covered and learnt in that level. So, for each level, the content is fixed, but the overall format is the same. There are three parts if you like - title, icon, and description. If the description were just text it would be easy (a view model containing the title image and text that I then bind the view to), but think of the description like the contents of a word document or web page -aligned images, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataTriggers to change the template. Let's say you have a view model with a property that you want to use to determine how your control is displayed, for the sake of argument I'll make it an enum:

```
public enum SomeFlag
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    TypeC
};

public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private SomeFlag _Flag = SomeFlag.TypeA;
    public SomeFlag Flag
    {
        get { return this._Flag; }
        set { this._Flag = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

All you need to do is add a style to a parent control/window and then add data triggers for each value:

```
<Control>

    <Control.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="{x:Static local:SomeFlag.TypeA}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="I am type A" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="{x:Static local:SomeFlag.TypeB}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="I am type B" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="{x:Static local:SomeFlag.TypeC}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="I am type C" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Control.Style>

</Control>
```

Comment: Hi Mark. This looks like it may be the answer I'm after. It hadn't occurred to me to simply use a lightweight view model to decide what I wanted to display :-) My only reservation is that currently the overall structure of the project is separated by level, and this would put all of the introductions for all of the levels in the one file. Is there a way I could separate these into multiple xaml files and still have it work?

Comment: @MikeNash yep, that's easy enough. In my example above I embedded the templates directly where they were needed, but they can also be static resources. If you want them in separate files then just create a ResourceDictionary file for each template, then in your App.xaml file's `<Application.Resources>` block you put a single `<ResourceDictionary>` block containing your global resources along with a `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` that includes each XAML template file. Can also be done in a more local scope, if you need details then let me know and we can take this over to chat.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the extra pointers @Mark Feldman. I should be able to sort out the MergedDictionary, but thanks for the offer - I'll give you a shout if I get stuck.

Comment: All good. One last thing to keep in mind is that you can also [bind directly to data in XML files](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/04/binding-to-xml/). I didn't cover that as it's not directly related to your question, but it can be quite useful when you want to keep your underlying data isolated from the GUI elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't viewmodel for this you can add/remove elements using Content property on runtime. 
In other case you can use ContentTemplateSelector property of ContentPresenter.

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton, this looks interesting. I've never used a template selector before, but presumably this is a class that I would have to write? How does this compare to Mark Feldman's answer below? I wonder if the template selector class here may be more heavyweight than the viewmodel/datatrigger arrangement in the other answer?

Comment: Yes - you need implement own selector which derived from DataTemplateSelector and also create resource in xaml (there are many examples in internet how to write it).    
Instead of triggers datatemplateselector can be contain more complex logic for select **datatemplate**( not template ). Since dataTemplate are different from Template - so you need decide what you need change in given case.

Comment: Thanks Anton. In this case my logic for how to choose the data template, so I think I'm going to go with the other answer. Thanks for your help.